# How to integrate sencha with struts2?

Tags: struts2

How struts 2 interceptors will receive sencha json format request. Please give some example of integration.

Comment: Like any other json request. Have you looked at the json or rest plugins? Have you sent a json request to see what happens?

Comment: @Dave Newton : I new to struts 2. I want to know how json request parse in struts 2 interceptor. Which plugin should use ? If u can please send one example. First i want to know how simple javascript(not ext javascript - sencha) send json request and how it get processed in struts 2..... please help me

Answer (score 0):

(Moved to answer for space purposes, this is more of an extended Q&A than answer.)

Why do you want to parse JSON in an interceptor?

Interceptors are for functionality across an entire application–if you have a specific JSON parameter you need in a lot of actions, consider using a base action class and putting your interceptor *after* the JSON interceptor and just querying the action for the parameter instead. Otherwise you're parsing JSON twice.

If it's *not* for functionality present across a large portion of the app, then you almost certainly shouldn't be doing the work in an interceptor, but rather an action. To implement this you can use either just the JSON interceptor, or the REST plugin, which handles a lot of other things as well.

There are examples of these in the Struts 2 distribution, but if you have a specific question, it might be easier to ask a real question here or on the Struts user mailing list. Asking for an example is redundant, because the distribution includes examples of most S2 functionality.